# Having issues creating a javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm attempting to create a JavaScript array and add objects to that array. I'm looping through the fields in a page and creating an object to add to the array at that time (see code) but for some reason when creating a new object the whole page of javascript code stops working. Am I doing something wrong in creating the object? Should I be doing it differently?

When I remove the "FArray[i] = {}" code and the rest of the code in the page starts working again.

```
function SetFields()
{
      var FArray = new Array(FieldSet.length);
      for (var i = 0; i < FieldSet.length; i++)
      {
            FArray[i] = { ID = FieldSet[i].ID, Value = document.getElementById(FieldSet[i].ID).value };
      }
      alert(FArray.length);
}

var FieldSet;
```

Comment: `FieldSet.length === 0`, so loop never runs. Event if `FieldSet` has a length it would have to be an Array of Objects, each Object having an `ID` property... not to mention that is not proper Object syntax anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create an object you should use a colon not an equals sign.

e.g.

```
let myObj = {id: 1, value: 2}
```

Comment: It's the small things in life, it looks like that was it.